# Defining a trajectory for a quadrotor

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, quadcopter, movement

I' m looking for a trajectory generator (the algorithm doesn't matter, since I m going to write it using C++ ) that generates a trajectory (a parametric curve in space) defined point by point which is going lately to be feed into my quadrotor drivers.

I'm honest: I don't know where to start.

1. **Reading** the following interesting [answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/2260/7097). But the problem here is: the trajectory has a PD controller with it. My quadrotor should take just a parametric curve as input.
2. [**OMPL**](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/OMPL_Primer.pdf): this library seems very powerful and interesting. It let the user to define a planner which many different algorithms. The problem is that it is not well documented, good examples and explanations are missing and till now I could'nt find anything related to quadrotors, which does use that library. There is an example for a quadrotor, which doesn't find my expectations and I cannot figure out, how to implement it in my package. I don't want just copy and paste code that I don't understand.
3. **B-Spline and Bezier Curve**...and the whole family of parametric curves. I found very interesting libraries in internet that implement those algorithm directly C++. The problem here is: I can define some points in space, generate a spline that contains them and interpolate points for the PID controller in the quadrotor. The basic idea is like a dog chasing a rabbit. A point is generated from the start point of the spline and regularly sent to the quadrotor. The latter flies behind the point, trying to reach it until a goal point has been reached. What is the problem here?!? In this case I can only generate a curve based on geometric properties and not considering the **dynamic** and the **kinematic** of the quadrotor (which I would consider for a future project). The rabbit runs and has a tighter curve radius than the dog, which could result in a strange behavior of the quadrotor.

I'd like same good tips to point to the right direction.

Which kind of trajectory planner are usually developed fr such an application?

Thanks!
Regards

Comment: Shouldn't a good controller free you from dynamics concerns when specifying a trajectory?

Comment: Could you be more specific Daniel?

Comment: A controller needs anyway a sort of a path or trajectory to follow

Comment: What I mean: If you already have an acceleration-based controller, you can pretty much go ahead with defining a trajectory with B-splines or whatever you like. Note, however, the difference between a trajectory and a path: the former defines *positions and velocities*, the latter *just positions*, without any velocity information.

Comment: I still don't understand what do you mean specifically. I wrote a controller using a backstepping integrator technique [link](http://etd.lib.metu.edu.tr/upload/12617592/index.pdf) pp.39. I acts on position, velocity. Acceleration is feedforwarded (in my code I put it simply to zero).

Comment: About the trajectory: I want to be able to generate (given some 3D control points) a spline which connect them. For every interpolation point (between the 3D control points) I need to define position, velocity, aceleration. I put wrongly path in my previous comment

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not very well versed in trajectory planning, but perhaps libraries like www.roboticslibrary.org/ or MRPT ( http://www.mrpt.org/ ) provide something helpful.

Comment: @Dave, may I ask you how did you implement the position control in the paper you mentioned? In my code, `arcsin()` yields undefined number due to the fact that `Ux*sin(psi) + Uy*cos(psi)` is out of `arcsin` domain.

Comment: @CroCo Yes: the problem is that in your case - somehow - the variables Ux and Uy are > than 1.
Be sure that you use the right equations (3.39 and 3.40) (the multiplication with the term (m/U1) is for this reason very important). If everything is nice then you should check your parameter coefficients ($\alpha_{7}, \alpha_{8}$ and so on....AND the computatioon of U1 must be bone BEFORE any other calculations: Otherwise m/U1 gives...infinity as a result. Keep us informed

Comment: @Dave, I have two questions, how did you tune  parameter coefficients? Second, which ODE solver did you use? I'm using Euler method because it is a fixed size step.

Comment: Ok: 1- with try&error. I started with some coefficients found in a paper and than I tried with small adjustments;
2- Since I ve programmed in C++, I was not constrained to use an integrator provided by matlab or simulink. In C++ you have to write yours. I personally used the Runge-Kutta 4th Order to integrate from acceleration to position. I suggest to read this [link](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/) which explains the difference very well

Comment: @Dave, thank you again for being patient and informative. Actually I'm using `Runge-Kutta` in boost library. In your code, is there any constrain on the generated angles? In my code, `DesiredPsi = atan2( Yd - x[2], Xd - x[0] );

  DesiredPhi = asin(  Ux*sin( DesiredPsi ) - Uy*cos( DesiredPsi )  );
    
  DesiredTheta = asin(   (Ux*cos(DesiredPsi) + Uy*sin(DesiredPsi))  / cos(DesiredPhi)   );` with no constrains.

Comment: Also, are there any constrains on the range of `asin` in your code? Or you simply chose the parameters in such a way that the value that is passed to `asin` in the proper range of `asin`.

Comment: For attitude control, backstepping is working with me.

Comment: Yes, I did a saturation function. The resulting angle may not be > than 89 deg. BUT the problem in your code is the way you are calculating Ux and Uy.

Comment: Here a piece of my code with the backstepping integrator: [link](http://pastebin.com/LWCtWNQm) The terms $Kx_, Ky_$ are for aerodynamics effects so you can put them = 0

Comment: @Dave, thank you so much. It is now working. great. It seems the problem with parameters' values. This causes $U_{x}, U_{y}$ to be high. Can you share `a saturation function` how did you implemented? Thank you again for being informative and helpful. I really appreciate your kindness